# How to conditionally load javascript file on view page

Tags: views, theming, javascript

I'm trying to load some theme javascript only to one view(multiple displays). I've tried to use the views preprocessor funciton, but maybe I'm doing it wrong:

```
function themename_preprocess_views_view__viewname__page(&$variables){
  this doesn't run on view page;
}
```

I've also tried it with the function name `themename_views_view()`. There's not much documentation on this.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_views_view().
 */
function themename_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  if ($view->name == 'view_name') {
    // Standardize the output for rows.
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'themename') . '/js/js_name.min.js', array('scope' => 'footer'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place this in your `template.php` and clear cache

```
<?php
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];

  if($view->name == 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME' && $view->current_display == 'YOUR_DISPLAY') {

    global $theme_path;
    drupal_add_js($theme_path . '/js/myfile.js');
    //OR MAYBE
    drupal_add_library('system','ui.slider');
  }
}
```